# How to get row count from flat file destination?

Tags: ssis

I am redirecting error rows from ole db destinationn table to flat file destination, here i need error rows count which are getting redirect to flat file and if count(error rows)>50 then my ssis package should fail.

And the data loaded into the table should get rollback if count(error rows)>50

How can i achive this?

Comment: You can use a Row Component
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141136(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I mean a Row Count component

Answer (score 1):

Use the row count task in the data flow, chain it to your error constraint from the OLEDB task. You might want to configure the row count to write to a variable since you'll be using row count in an expression (in which case you should create a variable called User::RowCount). Finally you can evaluate the condition Count(User::RowCount) > 0 by using a conditional split - all within the data flow task